# React authentication routes do not work in production build (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

My application uses an express/nodejs backend and reactjs frontend.

Whenever I go to login/logout (i.e hit the /auth-outlook etc.) routes in my production build of my application the route will update in the searchbar but will not update the actual application route.

Here is my *routes.js*:

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html"));
  });
  app.get("/api/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
  });

  app.get("/api/current_user", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
  });
  app.get(
    "/auth/outlook",
    passport.authenticate("windowslive", {
      scope: [
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "offline_access",
        "https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Read"
      ]
    })
  );
  app.get("/authorize-outlook", passport.authenticate("windowslive"), function(
    req,
    res
  ) {
    res.redirect("/");
  });
};
```

My *server.js* file has the following lines then:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
require("./routes/authRoutes")(app);
```

I have left out the SQL calls in my routes file for clarity purposes.

This application works 100% as intended when it's running its development version (i.e. `npm run start` and `nodemon server.js` separately).

Basic file structure of project:

1. client/
2. routes/

   3. authRoutes.js
3. server.js

TLDR: Application authentication routes do not work in production build of my project but do work in the development build.

Any information that would help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is a an example use of the React usage with backend:

```
import React from 'react';
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
import '../styles/landing.css';

const params = {
  particles: {
    number: {
      value: 100,
      density: {
        enable: true,
        value_area: 800
      }
    },
    color: {
      value: '#cccccc'
    },
    shape: {
      type: 'circle',
      stroke: {
        width: 0,
        color: '#cccccc'
      },
      polygon: {
        nb_sides: 5
      }
    },
    opacity: {
      value: 0.5,
      random: false,
      anim: {
        enable: false,
        speed: 1,
        opacity_min: 0.1,
        sync: false
      }
    },
    size: {
      value: 3,
      random: true,
      anim: {
        enable: false,
        speed: 40,
        size_min: 0.1,
        sync: false
      }
    },
    line_linked: {
      enable: true,
      distance: 150,
      color: '#cccccc',
      opacity: 0.4,
      width: 1
    },
    move: {
      enable: true,
      speed: 6,
      direction: 'none',
      random: false,
      straight: false,
      out_mode: 'out',
      bounce: false,
      attract: {
        enable: false,
        rotateX: 600,
        rotateY: 1200
      }
    }
  },
  interactivity: {
    detect_on: 'canvas',
    events: {
      onhover: {
        enable: true,
        mode: 'repulse'
      },
      onclick: {
        enable: true,
        mode: 'push'
      },
      resize: true
    },
    modes: {
      grab: {
        distance: 400,
        line_linked: {
          opacity: 1
        }
      },
      bubble: {
        distance: 400,
        size: 40,
        duration: 2,
        opacity: 8,
        speed: 3
      },
      repulse: {
        distance: 200,
        duration: 0.4
      },
      push: {
        particles_nb: 4
      },
      remove: {
        particles_nb: 2
      }
    }
  }
};

const Testing = () => (
  <div style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
    <div id="particles">
      <Particles
        params={params}
        style={{
          background:
            'linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(136,133,191,1) 0%, rgba(19,155,166,1) 45%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%)',
          padding: '0!important'
        }}
      />
      <div className="centered">
        <h1 className="headingLg">TQS Travel</h1>
        <p>
          Travel, made <i>easy</i>.
        </p>
        <div
          className="btn-group center"
          role="group"
          aria-label="Basic example"
        >
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-light btn-lg"
            style={{ marginRight: 10, color: 'black', width: 150 }}
          >
            <a
              className="nav-link"
              href="/auth/outlook"
              style={{ color: 'black' }}
            >
              Login
            </a>
          </button>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">
            Request Access
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Testing;
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem in the front-end rather than in the back-end. Can we see the React code? Any errors in the console? Are you building with different NODE_ENV environment variables for production and development?

Comment: @ThomasFussell I have edited and added one simple example within my application, the above code is a landing page. You click the link for login and should redirect to outlook for auth etc. Anything there point to something?

Comment: I don't see anything that should be causing problems there. My next area to investigate would be in `password-windowslive`. Since you say it works in development but not production builds, could you confirm that you're passing environment variables correctly to initialize the `WindowsLiveStrategy`? Do you see errors in the Chrome dev tools or the Express terminal? If you visit `/auth/outlook` directly, does it load correctly? Is your Windows Live OAuth redirect URI correct?

Comment: @ThomasFussell I attempted to go to the route and it is the same as all other routes, page stays the same it'll do what looks like a quick reload but no route update occurs. Even attempting to logout etc does nothing. This whole thing works in development I am at wits end now. Someone else gave the suggestion that my idea of routing in SPAs is completely wrong but I cannot find a concrete example that works online. MySQL routes also don't work. The application loads with error message regarding fetching data from that route.

Comment: Believe me, I know the feeling... I just noticed that you have a wildcard route before your other routes. I'm not sure why production vs. deployment would affect this, but I think you should move your wildcard `app.get('*', ...)` below all of the other routes since they are handled in order in Express and the wildcard matches all routes. If this solves the problem, I can write a full answer for you to accept.